# 3D rotation around fixed axes

Tags: math, 3d, linear-algebra, x3dom

I need axis and angle for rotation around 3 **fixed** axes.
What I want:

*input*:

- angle alpha (rotation round fixed x-axis)
- angle beta (rotation round
  fixed y-axis)
- angle gamma (rotation round fixed z-axis)

*ouput*:

- rotation axis with angle

The problem is that I always rotate around the already rotated axes.
My code so far:

```
 var q1 = x3dom.fields.Quaternion.axisAngle(new x3dom.fields.SFVec3f(0, 0, 1), alpha)
 var q2 = x3dom.fields.Quaternion.axisAngle(new x3dom.fields.SFVec3f(1, 0, 0), beta)
 var q3 = x3dom.fields.Quaternion.axisAngle(new x3dom.fields.SFVec3f(0, 1, 0), gamma)

 var qr = q1.multiply(q2);
 qr = qr.multiply(q3);
 var r = qr.toAxisAngle();

 this.curNode.attr('rotation', r[0].x + ' ' + r[0].y + ' ' + r[0].z + ' ' + r[1]);
```

[Video](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2niX0nXor): only one rotation is around the ring (red one) is right. the other two are around the rotated object axes. They should be around the *fixed* axes

Comment: What's your problem with the code? Have you tried to reverse the rotation order?

Comment: this is more a mathematical problem

Comment: I still don't see your problem.

Comment: upated: video for clarifying

Comment: Are you sure `SFVec3f(1, 0, 0)` refers to the y-axis?  And keep in mind that rotations are not commutative, if you apply them in the wrong order you get a wrong result.

Comment: Then you should not store the object's rotation as three angles, but as one quaternion (or matrix). Then you can multiply a new rotation to this quaternion and dont have to care about any rotation order.

Comment: +1 for Nico. Thinking in terms of angles to represent orientations in 3d usually (like with this issue) adds unnecessary complexity to the system. Store your orientation as a Matrix or Quat and discover simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is very well explained on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) Only instead of normal two turns you have three of them. So, you have to multiply not 2, but three matrices of flat turns. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are rotateing the local node axis, to mantani axis fixed you need to use  inverse quaternion for the node, but only for the node, to compute rotation, you need to use  original quaternion. Like this:

```
var q1 = x3dom.fields.Quaternion.axisAngle(new x3dom.fields.SFVec3f(0, 0, 1), alpha)
 var q2 = x3dom.fields.Quaternion.axisAngle(new x3dom.fields.SFVec3f(1, 0, 0), beta)
 var q3 = x3dom.fields.Quaternion.axisAngle(new x3dom.fields.SFVec3f(0, 1, 0), gamma)

 var qr = q1.multiply(q2);
 qr = qr.multiply(q3);
 var r = qr.toAxisAngle();

r  = r.inverse();

 this.curNode.attr('rotation', r[0].x + ' ' + r[0].y + ' ' + r[0].z + ' ' + r[1]);
```

If you want before recover node value, you must to invert it to compute it, and invert it the result to use it the node again.